# Problemas para comparar dados de duas matrizes com tamanhos diferentes no MatLab

Tags: matlab

Eu tenho uma matriz de dados, com anos não-bissextos, e em que matriz foi separada:

Dados = [ano mês dia dados1 dados2];

Tamanho = 14965 linhas e 5 colunas

E eu tenho um array parâmetros, para comparar com "dados1" e "dados2", com tamanho 365 linhas e 2 colunas, onde na coluna 1 tenho o parâmetro x1 para comparar com "dados1" e na coluna 2 tenho x2 para comparar Com "dados2".

Parâmetros = [x1 x2]

O parâmetro x1 deve ser comparado a "dados1" diariamente, onde eu deveria analisar se "dados1"> x1. O mesmo deve ser feito para "dados2" em relação a x2.

Estou tendo problemas para criar um método ou um loop para fazer essas comparações diárias e de todos os anos da matriz "Dados".

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro sua dúvida. Contudo... pelo o que eu consegui imaginar...

Dados tem 14965 linhas referente a 41 anos de dado, confere? 
dados1 e dados2 com 365 linhas referente a 1 ano de dado, confere?

```
ano_analise = 1; 
id_dado_ano = (ano_analise-1)*(1:100);
comparacao_diaria = Dados(id_dado_ano,[4 5])>[x1 x2];
percentagem_anual = sum(comparacao_diaria)./size(comparacao_diaria,1)
```

faz sentido?